# todo list checkbox numbering logic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a todo list with add and mark as completed feature. The li item have to be unique because I used `label for each checkbox on each li`.

then I use `$('ul li').length + 1;` to set their label for ID. so each checkbox is unique.

the problem is I used `remove()` when the checkbox is checked. it ruined the numbering. for example `I have 1,2,3 and I checked 1,2 then I add a new item`, that item will have ID 3, which is a clash. Any solution?

Comment: showing us fiddle would be better to help

Comment: instead of setting id using length, set id as something like todo-3 and separate the last one on "-", convert to int, increment and set as id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on their count to get unique IDs. Here is a function that returns a unique ID each time it is called:

```
function getUid(prefix) {
  return prefix + '_' +  getUid.count++;
}
getUid.count = 0;


console.log(getUid('checkbox')); // checkbox_0
console.log(getUid('checkbox')); // checkbox_1
console.log(getUid('checkbox')); // checkbox_2
console.log(getUid('checkbox')); // checkbox_3
console.log(getUid('li')); // li_4
```

Really safe solution (private variable):

```
var getUid = function() {
  var count = 0;
  return function(prefix) {
    return prefix + '_' +  count++;
  };
}();
```

Comment: I think a global variable and and a ++ counter variable after the item is created will do?

Comment: Sure, that's the idea. I find the function to be more explicit, so you can't confuse the variable's purpose in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some class on all the checkbox labels, Why not just use `parseInt($('.label-class').last().text()) + 1`? While I agree with other posters that this probably isn't a clean, universal solution... it is probably good enough by the sound of it.

If you're not getting the answer you're looking for, try adding more detail to the question. It's not clear what you're asking.